# How to Replace One Column Value Based on Another Column's Value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database called "images_db"

In that database I have a table called "image_table"

Within the table I have many columns, two of which are importance - "image_size" and "image_size_type".

The "image_size" column has size information for a large and small version of an image. It's written in this format: {"large":[2587,3493],"small":[444,600]} . For this particular example, it means the large image is 2587px in width and 3493px in height while the small image is 444px in width and 600 in height.

The "image_size_type" column has a value of either "large" or "small".

This is what the table/columns look like

[image]

How can I search and replace the "image_size_type" value for all rows in a table based on image size? What query must I run if I to replace the "image_size_type" to large when the "image_size" row has a large image size equal to or bigger than EITHER 2000px in width OR 2000px in height?

While hardly 'minimal', here's the useful bit:

Comment: Can you provide a SQLFillde ? http://sqlfiddle.com/ or https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Comment: And precise your MySQL version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you colums isn't a `JSON` type, you can do somthing like this :

```
UPDATE image_table
SET image_size_type = IF(
    CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(image_size, '$.large[0]') AS UNSIGNED) >= 2000
        OR CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(image_size, '$.large[1]') AS UNSIGNED) >= 2000,
    'large',
    'small'
)
```

Comment: thank you @Bazaim, i need one without JSON, but this did not work for me. I get the error #1305 - FUNCTION images_db.JSON_EXTRACT does not exist

Comment: Does `JSON_EXTRACT` work if it's not a JSON datatype?

Comment: Database version is 5.6

Comment: This is why I asked for the MySQL version, all JSON functions appear on 5.7 and can't be used une 5.6. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Comment: @Barmar Yes, you can use it on any string with MySQL 5.7 (i assume it's the same for 8.0)

Comment: thank you, i upgraded my database to 5.7 and this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using a version of MySQL with JSON functions:

```
UPDATE image_table
SET image_size_type = 
    CASE WHEN image_size->"$.large[0]" >= 2000 OR image_size->"$.large[1]" >= 2000
        THEN 'large'
        ELSE 'small'
    END
```

If you're not using the JSON datatype, it would probably be best to do this using an external programming language with a JSON library. Parsing JSON without a library will not be reliable, and is extremely difficult in a language like SQL, which doesn't have very advanced string processing.

Comment: thank you @Barmar, how do I convert to JSON datatype? i'm confused how i would do this with something like php if it doesn't work directly in mysql

Comment: Fetch each row, do `$json = json_decode($row['image_size']);` , then `if ($json->large[0] >= 2000 || $json->large[1] >= 2000)` around a call that updates the row appropriately.